# JSfiddle no me sirve

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

Me parece raro que cuando entro a los ejemplos de otros usuarios y sobre escribo con mi código html, altero las fuentes externas. Mi ejemplo jsFidle funciona. Al contrario si estoy en mi cuenta empezando un jsfidle desde cero no me funciona aun revisando El JAVASCRIPT (engrane) config.

Ejemplo de un Jsfidle cualquiera en el cual sobre escribí con mi código y material externo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este otro es mi jsfidle de cero, son los mismos external resources y configuraciones en el javascript:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tal vez alguien me ayuda a ver cual es mi ignorancia en esto.

[Aqui está mi jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/nacs2025/qpn5L34j/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estas llamando tus librerías sin el protocolo https, los navegadores no permiten recursos cruzados, es decir que si la pagina esta siendo llamada a través de https como jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nacs2025/qpn5L34j/

No puedes llamar tus librerías a traves de http:

http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css

Para solucionar el problema cambia las urls de tus librerias a urls que sean a través de https.

Aqui te dejo un jsfiddle funcional en base al tuyo: https://jsfiddle.net/59cd635k/

Para mas información revisa:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Gracias por la explicación.